# Como redireccionar a una ventana 404 en node js al meter por url una url que no exista

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, error404, http-get

Buenas estoy haciendo una app en nodejs pero al meter en la url /a me dicce Cannot get /a, me gustaría que cada vez que pasase algo de este estilo, redireccionar a una ventana /404, como podría hacer que me mandase a una 404 cada vez que metiese una url que no exista?? mi código actual en el index.js es este

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.hbs');
});

app.get('/index', login, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.hbs');
});
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?? Muchas gracias

Comment: De la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), debes usar las rutas en cascada. Por lo tanto, primero invierte el orden de lo que muestras en tu pregunta, y al final agrega: `app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.render('404.hbs') });`. Saludos

Comment: Y en un proyecto con casi mas de 80 rutas, como tengo que ordenarlo??

Comment: No es necesario, encontré esta solución:

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
    return res.send('404');
});

Comment: En un proyecto con más de 80 rutas lo mejor es usar el objeto [Router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router), yo comenté basado en lo que muestras en tu pregunta. Saludos